# why can't i use gcc on visual studio code?

Tags: c++, g++

I have installed g++ on Windows.Later I added the compiler path to the windows 10 environment variables.But how can i add g++ compiler on visual studio code? I tried many guides on youtube but they didn't help me, in fact I can't see the lunch.json file

Comment: Typo - `lunch.json` vs `launch.json` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a task file: Create a task file, so tasks.json in .vscode. If you don't already have one, open the command pallet (it's in view) and type task then press configure task file.

If you do have a task file: Once you have the task file in command type
`"command": "{Path to g++.exe}\\g++.exe",` with `\\` for directories instead of `/` or `\`.

Mine is `"G:\\Apps\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe"`.

Then, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> in the file you want to compile and press your task file.

Comment: Sorry about the delayed answer